# Problem with citation of authors having user defined command in their names

Tags: biblatex, indexing, imakeidx, def, polski

I have a problem using `polski` package simultaneously with `imakeidx` and `biblatex`.
I only use the command `\dywiz` from package `polski` which is defined as `\def\dywiz{\kern0sp\discretionary{-}{-}{-}\penalty10000\hskip0sp\relax}`

The command is used to control the hyphenation of two-part (hyphenated) words.
Everything works fine except when I use it for the names of authors who also need to be indexed in the `bib` file.

When I use command `\index{Kowalski\dywiz Jankowski, Karol}` in text I get this entry in the `ind` file: `\indexentry{Kowalski\dywiz Jankowski, Karol}{1}` which is great.

When I use command `author = {Kowalski\dywiz Jankowski, Karol}`, in my `bib` file I get spurious space in text, spurious space in bibliography and extra item in my index (because of entry `\indexentry{Kowalski\kern 0sp\discretionary {-}{-}{-}\penalty 10000\hskip 0sp\relax  Jankowski, Karol}{1}` in my `ind` file).

Partial solution is to use command `author = {Kowalski\dywiz{}Jankowski, Karol}` in my `bib` file. That eliminates spurious spaces in text and in bibliography but unfortunately it produces one more extra entry in my index (because of entry `\indexentry{Kowalski\kern 0sp\discretionary {-}{-}{-}\penalty 10000\hskip 0sp\relax  {}Jankowski, Karol}{1}` in my `ind` file).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[indexing=cite,style=verbose-trad1,dashed=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=1]

%remove titles from index
\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
    \ifciteindex
        {\indexnames{labelname}%
         \indexnames{editor}%
         \indexnames{editora}%
         \indexnames{editorb}%
         \indexnames{translator}%
     \indexnames{commentator}}
        {}} 

\def\dywiz{\kern0sp\discretionary{-}{-}{-}\penalty10000\hskip0sp\relax} %actually I use \usepackage{polski} but the result is the same

    
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{plbook1,
  author        = {Kowalski\dywiz Jankowski, Karol}, %spurious space in both text citation and the bibliography, extra entry in index
  title         = {Book1 title},
}

@book{plbook2,
  author        = {Kowalski\dywiz{}Jankowski, Karol}, %no spurious space but one more extra entry in index
  title         = {Book2 title},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{plbook1} %this produces \indexentry{Kowalski\kern 0sp\discretionary {-}{-}{-}\penalty 10000\hskip 0sp\relax  Jankowski, Karol}{1}

\cite{plbook2} %this produces \indexentry{Kowalski\kern 0sp\discretionary {-}{-}{-}\penalty 10000\hskip 0sp\relax {}Jankowski, Karol}{1}

\index{Kowalski\dywiz Jankowski, Karol} %this produces \indexentry{Kowalski\dywiz Jankowski, Karol}{1}

\printindex

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

To sum up, I have two problems:

1. unnecessary space in some cases when using `\dywiz`.
2. using user defined commands in the authors names in the `bib` file causes that command to be written in full explicit form in the `ind` file (`\indexentry{Kowalski\kern 0sp\discretionary {-}{-}{-}\penalty 10000\hskip 0sp\relax  Jankowski, Karol}{1}` instead of just  `\indexentry{Kowalski\dywiz Jankowski, Karol}{1}`).